# Updating Phonenumbers in AD via csv with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-cmdlet

Please guys, help me out here.

I have created a file with the following command:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties samAccountName,DistinguishedName,telephoneNumber | select-object samAccountName,DistinguishedName,telephonenumber,address,city | Export-Csv C:\Shares\TESTSHARE\new3.csv -notypeinformation -delimiter ";" -Encoding utf8;
```

This works like a charm, but for the love of god, I cannot manage to import it again, all I wanna do is change the phonenumbers in the excel sheet, and insert the altered file into the AD.

Basically this has robbed me three days worth of time already, and my client is becoming edgy..

**EDIT:**

I tried to run the script which was posted by Ansgar Wiechers but unfortunately I got a few error messages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the complementary cmdlets in reverse order:

```
$csv = 'C:\Shares\TESTSHARE\modified3.csv'

Import-Csv $csv -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8 | % {
  Get-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName |
    Set-ADUser -OfficePhone $_.telephonenumber
}
```

**Edit:** Your error messages suggest that you try to assign empty telephone numbers. Verify that by adding the following line before `Get-ADuser`:

```
Write-Output "{0} [{1}]" -f $_.samAccountName, $_.telephonenumber
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback! unfortunately this script does not run without errors. Please have a look at the message, maybe you already know the solution :) http://de.tinypic.com/r/2rrqs89/8

Comment: @flog Please update your question with the error message. Or at least post the picture in a place that doesn't require JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have added the things you have requested, thank you again for taking the time!

Comment: I tried your 2nd Solution, but I only got more error messages, I'm sorry for being such a hassle. http://codepaste.net/bgg1jt

Comment: @flog It's not a solution, it's a means to find out what's going on. You should still be getting the errors, but you'll see which values the code tries to change. And again, additional information should go into your *question*.